# OCaml: inner "let" for two functions

Tags: ocaml, let

I want to make inner "let", but for two functions.

I have now a function

```
let fresh_var () =
let r = ref 0 in
r := !r + 1 ; Var !r;;
```

I want to add second function so that it could change r, but r stays invisible for the rest of the program. Something like:

```
let r = ref 0 in 
let fresh_var () = r := !r + 1 ; Var !r
and let refresh () = r := 0
```

But piece above doesn't work because of syntax error.

How can I implement this idea in OCaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create one function returning a pair of functions:

```
let get_fresh_and_reset () =
  let r = ref 0 in
  (fun () -> incr r; !r), (fun () -> r := 0)

let fresh, reset = get_fresh_and_reset ()
```

Also note that the correct syntax is `:=` and not `=:`.

**Edit:**

As [@Virgile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1633665/virgile) mentioned, in case if you don't need several counters you can simplify:

```
let fresh_var, refresh =
    let r = ref 0 in (fun () -> incr r; !r), (fun () -> r:=0)
```

Comment: This lets you defining several independent counters, but in case just one is indeed, you can directly do `let fresh_var, refresh = let r = ref 0 in (fun () -> incr r; !r), (fun () -> r:=0)`

Comment: This feels very hackish but why not :p Does this have real world applications, or is it just a quirk of the language?

Comment: @Richard-Degenne, I don't know about the real world, but I don't feel it's a hack. Obviously, if you need some global counter structure it's better to use modules, but when it's just a small internal counter, I don't see any reason why not choose this solution.

Comment: You can also use named functions making this more readable when the code is longer: `let (fresh_var, refresh) = let r = ref 0 in let fresh_var () = incr r; !r in let refresh () = r:=0 in (fresh_var, refresh)`. More general use of this construct is to write a pair of getter/setter functions for a record field (references are just a mutable record) so they can be passed to a polymorphic function that has no knowledge of the record.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how things work in OCaml. *Local* definitions are exactly that, local. They cannot be shared between functions.

If you want to abstract part of your implementation, I suggest using modules instead.

```
module Incrementer : sig
  val next : unit -> int
  val reset : unit -> unit
end = struct
  let r = ref 0

  let next () =
    r := !r + 1;
    !r

  let reset () =
    r := 0
end
```

See it in action below:

```
# Incrementer.next ();;
- : int = 1

# Incrementer.next ();;
- : int = 2

# Incrementer.reset ();;
- : unit = ()

# Incrementer.next ();;
- : int = 1

# Incrementer.r;;
Error: Unbound value Incrementer.r
```

---

Below is a better implementation which allows you to have multiple `Incrementers` at once.

```
module Incrementer : sig
  type t
  val create : unit -> t
  val next : t -> int
  val reset : t -> unit
end = struct
  type t = int ref

  let create () =
    ref 0

  let next t =
    t := !t + 1;
    !t

  let reset t =
    t := 0
end
```

Let's see it in action:

```
# let incrementer = Incrementer.create ();;
val incrementer : Incrementer.t = <abstr>
(* As you can see, the outer code never sees the `int ref` inside. *)

# Incrementer.next incrementer;;
- : int = 1

# Incrementer.next incrementer;;
- : int = 2

# Incrementer.reset incrementer;;
- : unit = ()

# Incrementer.next incrementer;;
- : int = 1
```

---

You can also write the signature and the implementation in separate files in order to compile them separately.

Answer (score 0):

`and` is used instead of `let` when you want to write joint declarations, and `in` is only used in local contexts:

```
let r = ref 0
let fresh_var () = r := !r + 1 ; Var !r
and refresh () = r := 0
```

However, since your functions are not codependent the use of `and` is not necessary here so you could use another `let` construct.

As for the idea you have, you would have to define these functions in a seperate module whose `.mli` only declares them and not the variable `r`.

Comment: This does not address OP's requirements that "r stays invisible for the rest of the program"

Comment: If the `.mli` does not declare `r` it won't be visible from the rest of the program.

Comment: unless said program consists in a single module, or even a script to be fed to the interpreter.

Comment: That is true but I don't understand how you infered that this was a constraint?

Comment: I don't know if that is a constraint in this particular case. My point is basically the same as Vonaka's comment under their answer: for such a simple case, it's much easier to define a pair of function sharing a local variable rather than going the whole `module` or `.mli` route.

Answer (score 0):

OCaml also supports a rich object-oriented system

```
class counter = object
  val mutable r = 0

  method value =
    r

  method incr =
    r <- r + 1;
    r

  method reset =
    r <- 0;
    0
end
```

We can use our `counter` like this

```
let () =
  let c = new counter in
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#value;   (* counter value: 0 *)
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#incr;    (* counter value: 1 *)
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#incr;    (* counter value: 2 *)
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#incr;    (* counter value: 3 *)
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#value;   (* counter value: 3 *)
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#value;   (* counter value: 3 *)
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#reset;   (* counter value: 0 *)
  printf "counter value: %d\n" c#incr;    (* counter value: 1 *)
```

Class instances encapsulate their data members, so we can easily manage multiple counters

```
let () =
  let a = new counter in
  let b = new counter in
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#value b#value;  (* A: 0, B: 0 *)
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#incr b#value;   (* A: 1, B: 0 *)
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#incr b#value;   (* A: 2, B: 0 *)
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#incr b#value;   (* A: 3, B: 0 *)
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#value b#incr;   (* A: 3, B: 1 *)
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#value b#incr;   (* A: 3, B: 2 *)
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#value b#incr;   (* A: 3, B: 3 *)
  printf "A: %d, B: %d\n" a#reset b#reset;  (* A: 0, B: 0 *)
```